# Build Cordova project for iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to build my Cordova project for an iOS. I have borrowed a mac and an iphone in order to do this; meaning I am very new to everything apple-related.

From what I understand: in order to build anything for iOS, I need some sort of apple developer-account. (I believe the mac I am using has one, not quite sure.)

When I try to run the command: `cordova run ios` I get the following error:

> Check dependencies
>   Code Signing Error: No profiles for 'io.cordova.hellocordova' were found:  Xcode couldn't find any iOS App Development provisioning profiles matching 'io.cordova.hellocordova'. Automatic signing is disabled and unable to generate a profile. To enable automatic signing, pass -allowProvisioningUpdates to xcodebuild.
>   Code Signing Error: Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 11.2'

I don't know what any of the above means, or how to solve it. I believe I have to use xcode to somehow automatically created a build.json file (not sure), but I don't know how to open my cordova project in xcode.

I have been using Sublime to edit my cordova project files, and the terminal to use the cordova cli. I am running xcode 9.2

Comment: You need Active Developer account in order to run app into your device.

Comment: @Dev_Tandel How do I get one of those?

Answer (score 3):

> From what I understand: in order to build anything for iOS, I need some sort of apple developer-account. (I believe the mac I am using has one, not quite sure.)

If that is true, then you can try the following:

```
cordova build ios
open platforms/ios/<my-app-name>.xcworkspace
```

This will open the app in Xcode. Click on the icon (left hand side, above the directory structure view) "General" and check "Automatically manage signing". Try to run the app in Xcode.

Check this website for reference (and a picture of where to click in Xcode): http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/7.x/guide/platforms/ios/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Dev_Tandel, you need to have a apple dev acct to run your app in a device. Refer link to get more info: https://developer.apple.com/support/certificates/